# Duda con ostream_iterator()

Tags: c++

En la siguiente linea : `std::ostream_iterator<int> salida(std::cout,"|");` se crea un iterador llamado salida que va a mostrar enteros en pantalla separados por una barrita vertical.

Esta linea: `copy(valores.begin(),valores.end(),salida);` Copia lo que esta en la lista valores y los manda al iterador salida.

No entiendo porque si el iterador esta declarado antes que la funcion `copy()` que en teoria es la que indica los datos a imprimir.

¿Porque imprime?

Osea ¿Primero itera y imprime y luego se mandan los datos?, no entiendo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>


int main(){
    std::list<int> valores;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        valores.push_back(i);
    }

    std::ostream_iterator<int> salida(std::cout,"|");
    copy(valores.begin(),valores.end(),salida);

    return 0;
}
```

Lo que decia de una variable name es lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::string name;
  std::cout<<name;
  name = "Hola";
}
```

En ese ejemplo creo una variable llamada name,la imprimo y luego le asigno un valor, esto no muestra nada, ¿No seria un caso parecido a lo de mas arriba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera de saber qué hace algo es probándolo, este código:

```
std::vector valores { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
std::ostream_iterator<int> salida(std::cout, "|");
std::copy(valores.begin(), valores.end(), salida);
```

[Produce la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##TY7BbsIwEETP@CtGcAliiYAW2kLKr6Ct40aWjB3ZDlIF/HpNEhK1xx3Ne7OyrpfSsK1SmmkrTVMqFNqF6BWfj@IvuygZnf@f6Kg895nQNuLM2mZzcRWTEMv9/tnHhY3zKuCKNWFDeCG8EraEHeGN8E74wP0wMMPsaTQXrfeIwEaXnPUN6ZpImN6m85GRrv7JhpX8S1XdEzTO5sqW3flUtIyYeBUbb7E6iHtKv/LbcBXSslV9ysViww8):

> ```
> 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|
> ```

Si consultamos el [constructor](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/ostream_iterator) del iterador:

> ```
> ostream_iterator(ostream_type& stream, const CharT* delim)
> ```
>
> Construye el iterador con `stream` como el flujo de datos asociado y `delim` como delimiitador.

En resumen es un iterador para flujo de salida de datos (***o***utput **stream**, flujo de salida) al que se le puede pasar una cadena para separar los datos que quiere mostrar en la salida.

---

> ¿Primero itera y imprime y luego se mandan los datos?

No, crear un iterador no hace que el iterador se mueva. Si consultamos la [definición de `std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
template< class InputIt, class OutputIt >
constexpr OutputIt copy( InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first );
```

Vemos que recibe tres iteradores como argumentos, los dos primeros indican desde dónde copiar y dónde detener la copia, el tercero indica el destino de la copia, la página *cppreference.com* nos ofrece también una *posible* implementación:

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
OutputIt copy(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first)
{
    while (first != last) {
        *d_first++ = *first++;
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Como podemos ver, no se itera hasta que se empieza a copiar, en otras palabras: copia un elemento y **después** avanza el iterador.

Comment: Claro,creo que me exprese mal en la pregunta, mas que nada lo que no entiendo es ¿Porque imprime algo si es en la linea siguiente que se le pasa lo que tiene que imprimir?, es el orden de las lineas lo que no entiendo.Lo pienso como si hiciera esto: ```std::cout<<name;``` y en la linea siguiente le asignara valor a la variable name,no se mostraria nada en pantalla porque al momento de imprimir name no tenia nada.

Comment: y en este caso al iterador salida no se le pasa mismo en la declaracion lo que tiene que imprimir, se le pasa en la linea siguiente con la funcion copy().

Comment: No entiendo ni una palabra de tu duda, @Franco . ¿Qué siguiente línea? ¿Dónde ves `std::cout<<name;`? ¿De qué variable `name` estás hablando, no hay ninguna variable así en tu código? ¿A qué te refieres con el orden de las líneas? Mejor edita tu pregunta con lo que realmente quieres saber, si no recibirás una respuesta que no te valga.

Comment: Voy a rehacer la pregunta @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: Actualicé las traducciones de `std::ostream_iterator` y `std::copy` en https://es.cppreference.com para que tengas una mejor experiencia con la respuesta provista por @PaperBirdMAster